# Why does the Esri-resource-proxy log users out of Esri Geoportal Server?

Tags: proxy, geoportal, esri-geoportal-server

I'm seeing a problem whereby passing a query to the [Esri Geoportal Server](http://esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal)'s REST API, via the [Esri Resource Proxy](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy), is causing users to be logged out of the Geoportal.

I can reproduce the problem like this:

- install the Esri Geoportal Server on Windows using IIS
- install the Esri Resource Proxy on the same machine
- log in to the Geoportal (eg http://localhost:8080/geoportal/catalog/identity/login.page)
- in a new tab in the same browser, send a query to the Geoportal REST API via the Esri proxy (eg http://localhost/PHP/proxy.php?http://localhost:8080/geoportal/rest/find/document?f=pjson)
- switch back to the Geoportal tab, refresh the page, and note that the user is now logged out

This error does *not* occur for me using the sandbox Geoportal at http://gptogc.esri.com/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page (you can test it with this [query](http://stephenlead.com/esri-proxy/PHP/proxy.php?http://gptogc.esri.com/geoportal/rest/find/document?&max=10&rid=local&f=pjson))

Does anyone know why this is occurring? Is the problem occurring because the proxy is on the same machine as the Geoportal Server? Are there any known workarounds?

I don't know enough about how the login session works in the Geoportal Server, or what the Esri Resource Proxy is doing, to know how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to cookies, which Geoportal Server uses to track login sessions. When the proxy is on the same domain as the Geoportal Server, it strips the cookies and resets the session.

One workaround is to put the proxy onto a separate subdomain.